# How to calculate cost of Amazon S3 for hosting my web application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Please I need your suggestons.

I want to calculate the cost of using Amazon S3 to host my web application. The size of the web application for now is about 6MB.

Users of the application will either post their details or do a search to retrieve from the system. There are no file uploads, except photo of users.

If you have used Amazon S3 to host your application, please kindly advice on how to calculate.

Thank you in advance.

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The storage cost will be minimal, but it is also dependent on request count and bandwidth usage, so the cost depends on how popular you'll be.

You can use the AWS Simple Monthly Calculator to estimate that: http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html

For small sites, that is likely to fit on the free tier:
http://aws.amazon.com/free

Comment: Hi Julio Faerman, thank you for your response. Your link as seen here http://aws.amazon.com/free provided the details I want.